# Login with Facebook Odoo python auth_oauth module

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth, odoo

I am trying to do login with facebook (OAuth) in Odoo using **auth_oauth** module,  It opens facebook page for login and after I enter appropriate login credentials it responses back to odoo, during that It throws following error:

**"You do not have access to this database or your invitation has expired. Please ask for an invitation and be sure to follow the link in your invitation email."**

While tracing I found that odoo tries to find the "user_id" from the response, which I don't find in the response provided by the faceobook, so I am not sure what am I missing.

This thing works fine with Google account Login.

**My Configuration:**

1./ I have configured the "App" in facebook, (so it may happen that I may be missing some configuration in Facebook App creation, not sure for this).

2./ In Odoo I have provided appropriate "App Id" in the "Client Id" in OAuth provider of Facebook record. The other thing is the **secret key** provided by facebook, I didn't entered it anywhere because I am not sure where to use it.

3./ My scope for facebook login is public_profile,email

[image]

Comment: Have you solved this? I have a similar problem

Comment: Can you post your solution, or what was the problem?

Comment: We need to do the "allow_uninvited" signup flag in the configurtation.

Comment: When registered using facebook, the email address is a dummy text, is there a way to obtain email address? Or is this FB restriction?